# Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: ssl, curl

I know it was answered before, i'm just wondering why nothing works for me:

If i want it to be fixed (this error is when i do the paypal ipn stuff) i need to do the following:

Go to my php.ini, at the end add the following:

```
curl.cainfo=C:\cacert.pem
```

right? well, it's not working, so are those:

```
curl.cainfo="C:\cacert.pem"
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CAPATH, "./cacert.pem");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "C:\cacert.pem");
```

Nothing works, i downloaded it from this site:
http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

What is missing?

(I don't know if it's worth mentioning, but im using windows with wamp, and localtunnel to test paypal IPN locally)

What could be the reason none of the above are working, all the other tutorials tells the same, but seems nothing to work for me, Things get moving only when i do this:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

Which i know it's not good, but i tried everything~!

Comment: Try reading the answer I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27494484

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same problem. No matter how many times I've downloaded the cacert.pem file, changed folder permissions and it still wouldn't work.

A quick search on my machine and found another cacert.pem used by a pyrocms installation I have.  I tried that one and it worked just fine.

I'm still trying to figure out why it doesn't work using the one suggested by the PayPal documentation, but in the meantime I can continue development. Hope this helps you out.

I've added the file to my dropbox so you can test it out: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7j6cf55sshjcqxm/cacert.pem?dl=0