# Laravel Socialite testing on localhost, SSL certificate issue?

Tags: laravel, facebook-social-plugins, laravel-5

To insert social login integration on my application, I'm adding Socialite library to my Laravel app. I have a facebook app registered and 2 methods as in laravel documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#social-authentication

```
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialize::with('github')->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    $user = Socialize::with('github')->user();
    dd($user);
}
```

The request gets submitted to and returned from Facebook sucessfully, but once I reach the callback URL: localhost:8000/social (where the handleProviderCallback()) is called, I get the following error:

> RequestException in RequestException.php line 51: 
>   cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

I have tried turning off my firewall, but had no success.. getting really frustrated, can someone help me out?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I found sollution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478283/paypal-access-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate). I've downloaded this file

http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

and set path in php.ini

```
[cURL] 
curl.cainfo=C:\php\cacert.pem
```

It works after server restart.

Comment: Thanks, solved the problem for me (on Windows host).

Comment: If you are using tools like grunt-php as your local server, make sure you stop the task and re-start it after changing this setting.

Comment: this helped me a lot, exactly as described, php folder, then the file and refresh terminal, it is working now, thanks