# Laravel 5.2 Socialite Facebook Login cURL error 60

Tags: php, facebook, ssl, curl

I'm getting an error **RequestException in CurlFactory.php line 187:
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)** when trying to login with socialite facebook. This is the tutorial I followed http://blog.damirmiladinov.com/laravel/laravel-5.2-socialite-facebook-login.html#.V2K-ersrLIV .

This is my controller:

```
public function redirect()
{
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();   
}   

public function callback()
{
    // when facebook call us a with token 
    $providerUser = \Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();   
}
```

From my research I found out the error is as a result ofthe version of guzzlehttp/guzzle.I tried the solutions provided in these links but it didn't work for me. [Laravel Socialite testing on localhost, SSL certificate issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28635295/laravel-socialite-testing-on-localhost-ssl-certificate-issue) and  https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/replies/52954. Kindly help.

Answer (score 10):

For those that still need a solution, here it is.

```
$providerUser = \Socialite::driver('facebook')
    ->setHttpClient(new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => false]))
    ->user();
```

Note the `['verify' => false]`, this disables the SSL certificate verification check done by the Guzzle HTTP client which is used by Socialite. It might also be a good idea to export this into the configuration as a setting.

Comment: `setHttpClient()` would be a very nice addition to Laravel Socialite docs.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for almost one month I have been able to solve my problem.
The problem was with `Cacert.pem` file which was missing in my php folder in xampp directory.
I downloaded new carcet.pem from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and saved it as carcet.pem.txt in my php folder inside the xampp directory. I then opened php.ini file inside php folder and changed
    `;curl.cainfo=` to 
    `curl.cainfo="C:\xampp\php\cacert.pem.txt"`. **Do not forget** the **.txt** extension and also don't forget to **restart your xampp**.
That solved the problem for me. You can also read more about this error here [Laravel 5 Socialite - cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30240840/laravel-5-socialite-curl-error-77-error-setting-certificate-verify-locations). Here is a link to the tutorial I followed to implement Facebook Socialite Login http://blog.sarav.co/integrating-socialite-in-laravel-5-2/.Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with the cacert.pem +
php artisan generate:key