# Laravel socialite issue cURL error 60: unable to get local issuer certificate using fb and google

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I am trying to test laravel socialite on wampserver i tried it on both google and facebook but it gives me the error:

```
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

i followed the solution on [Laravel Socialite testing on localhost, SSL certificate issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869680/laravel-5-2-socialite-facebook-login-curl-error-60)

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869680/laravel-5-2-socialite-facebook-login-curl-error-60): [Laravel Socialite testing on localhost, SSL certificate issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28635295/laravel-socialite-testing-on-localhost-ssl-certificate-issue)  and [Laravel 5.2 Socialite Facebook Login cURL error 60](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869680/laravel-5-2-socialite-facebook-login-curl-error-60) but still  the same problem is showing . Here is my code

```
 public function facebook()
    {
        return $this->socialite->with('facebook')->redirect();
    }

public function facebookCallback()
{
    $user = $this->socialite->with('facebook')->user();

   dd($user);

}
public function google()
{
    return $this->socialite->driver('google')->redirect();
}

public function googleCallback()
{
    $user = $this->socialite->driver('google')->user();


    dd($user);

}`
```

and my php.ini is: `curl.cainfo ="D:/programs/wamp64/bin/php/cacert.pem.txt"`I don't know what am i doing wrong.