# Laravel 5.2.31 Socialite certificate ssl error

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, ssl, curl

I'm using [Socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite) for my Facebook login. I was able to follow the steps [here](https://blog.damirmiladinov.com/laravel/laravel-5.2-socialite-facebook-login.html#.WAmWSeB97IU) until I was able to encouter a cURL certificate error upon clicking the "Continue as ..." on facebook oAuth.

> RequestException in CurlFactory.php line 187:
>   cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

I have download the `cacert.pem` and added it to my `php.ini` by following the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28635295/laravel-socialite-testing-on-localhost-ssl-certificate-issue).

```
[cURL]
curl.cainfo=C:\xampp\php\cacert.pem
```

Restarted apache and still the same error. I'm running it under a Windows machine. What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by checking the php path on the environment variables. I needed to add the php path on the `path`. This is to make sure that the PHP that I am running using `php artisan serve` is running the correct PHP instance.