# facebook auth cURL error 60: SSL certificate

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, curl, oauth

cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

tried multiple solution but not solving 
this all solutions i tried :
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-solve-curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-in-laravel-5-while-facebook-authentication
[Laravel Socialite testing on localhost, SSL certificate issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28635295/laravel-socialite-testing-on-localhost-ssl-certificate-issue)

```
public function getSocialAuth()
{
    return Socialite::driver('github')->redirect();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution. Tested.
You can open your php.ini file. 
Change this

```
;openssl.cafile=
```

to

```
openssl.cafile=C:/Windows/curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

(notice the semi colon is removed?)

Search your system for a file named curl-ca-bundle.crt and put it in C:/Windows

I expect it works on Mac and other sytems as well. Just put in the right path.
That's it.