# Facebook - Curl Error SSL_CACERT SSL certificate

Tags: facebook, apache, curl, iis, proxy

I am getting "**Curl Error : SSL_CACERT SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate**" when asking Facebook to [scrape my page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) over https. How can I fix this so that Facebook can scrape my page without errors?

The page is hosted via Apache 2.4 proxying to IIS 10. Apache handles all certificates and IIS is on the local network. My page is running asp code (so no php) and solutions similar to these: [edit the php.ini file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41019104/facebook-auth-curl-error-60-ssl-certificate) or [adding curl.pem to php folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869680/laravel-5-2-socialite-facebook-login-curl-error-60) will not work fix my problem ... or so I think?!?

IIS has no certificate installed.

I do have `extension=php_curl.dll` enabled -- and `extension_dir = 'C:\64bit\php-7.0.6-Win32-VC14-x64\ext'` defined in my php.ini file. I followed [these steps](http://www.web-site-scripts.com/knowledge-base/article/AA-00480/0/Curl-installation-on-Windows-Apache-and-IIS.html) to install Curl on Windows. And phpinfo.php confirms that cURL is enabled (cURL Information 7.47.1).

My proxy setup in my Apache config file is:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass           / http://192.168.1.101:88/com_ssl/
    ProxyPassReverse    / http://192.168.1.101:88/com_ssl/
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$  https://www.domainname.com/$1 [P,L] 
</IfModule>
```

I have no **RequestHeader** defined in my Apache proxy config file, [such as suggested here in Step 10](https://www.netnea.com/cms/apache-tutorial-9_setting-up-a-reverse-proxy/):

```
RequestHeader set "X-RP-UNIQUE-ID"     "%{UNIQUE_ID}e"
RequestHeader set "X-RP-REMOTE-USER"     "%{REMOTE_USER}e"
RequestHeader set "X-RP-SSL-PROTOCOL"     "%{SSL_PROTOCOL}s"
RequestHeader set "X-RP-SSL-CIPHER"     "%{SSL_CIPHER}s"
```

Is this what is missing to fix the error?

Comment: You can use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to test your setup.

Comment: @WizKid thank you for that link. I was getting an **F** - what a shock! I had no idea. I updated Apache from 2.4.20 to 2.4.36 and that bumped me up to a **B**. After that I comment out `SSLCertificateChainFile` and that bumped me up to an **A**. (I am not sure it the Facebook error was triggered due to the intermediate certificate problem.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"unable to get local issuer certificate" is almost always the error message you get when the server doesn't provide an [intermediate certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate#Types_of_certificate) as it should in the TLS handshake, and as WizKid suggests, running the [ssllabs test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) against the server will indeed tell you if that is the case.

Comment: I also think this is the most likely issue. I used the following tool to check that in the past and found it very simple/quick (a lot quicker than the Qualys check you suggest) to use: https://whatsmychaincert.com  (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49050648/7362396)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nodejs server and getting this error 'Curl Error SSL_CACERT SSL certificate' then you need to add your CA along with your SSL CRT.

```
var fs = require('fs'); 
var https = require('https'); 
var options = { 
    key: fs.readFileSync('server-key.pem'), 
    cert: fs.readFileSync('server-crt.pem'), 
    ca: fs.readFileSync('ca-crt.pem'), // <= Add This
}; 
https.createServer(options, function (req, res) { 
    console.log(new Date()+' '+ 
        req.connection.remoteAddress+' '+ 
        req.method+' '+req.url); 
    res.writeHead(200); 
    res.end("hello world\n"); 
}).listen(4433);
```

Comment: Your solution didn't actually help me, but it pointed me in the right direction to fix the issue. Turns out for the `cert` field I had to import the `fullchain.pem` file, not the `cert.pem` file (weird letsencrypt naming conventions)

Answer (score 0):

This may not have been the case at the time but I will add this info in case others encounter the same issue.

If you are using a CDN, like cloudflare, it is important to set up your SSL before adding to cloudflare as it can generate issues.

It is also important to ensure that all domains are correctly annotated in the DNS control of cloudflare, otherwise you may end up serving your main domain via cloudflare and your subdomain(s) directly from your server.  Whilst this wont matter much to the user (still shows secure, still have access, still passes SSL tests) it may flag issues with sharing apps onto social media.  Basically, I replicated the error by splitting the DNS setup as above and achieved the flagged error as highlighted by the op.  Then I added the DNS for the subdomain into cloudflare, tested a few hours later (after resetting the page in debudder: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fus.icalculator.info%2Fterminology%2Fus-tax-tables%2F2019%2Fvirginia.html).  and, hey presto, the error goes.  So, if you encounter that issue and you use cloudflare, that is something to check you have set up correctly.