# While I try to share my website link in facebook feeds it wont show images

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

While I try to share my website link in facebook feeds it wont show images
Facebook debugger provide this error,

Inferred Property
    The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
    Missing Properties
    The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id
    SSL Error
    Can't validate SSL Certificate. Either it is self-signed (which will cause browser warnings) or it is invalid.
    Curl Error
    Curl error: 60 (SSL_CACERT)

1. og tags are configured correctly and I am using seo yoast for open graph. It is updated to its latest version.
2. I am installing let's encrypt for my website.

Thanks,
Regards,
Vijay

Comment: Try [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51909994)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I ask my hosting provider to reinstall lets encrypt certificate. Let you know the result