# Laravel 5 Socialite - cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations

Tags: php, ssl, curl, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I am using socialite in Laravel 5 to setup facebook login. I followed the instructions carefully until I got stuck with the following error

```
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

so I found the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478283/paypal-access-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate) answer to fix it which indeed passed but then I got this error

```
cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations:
CAfile: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cacert.pem
CApath: none
```

Any ideas what's the cause of this error?! and how to fix it?!

Comment: Are you using a real SSL certificate or a self certified certificate? Does the /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cacert.pem file exist?

Comment: @detheridge02 I downloaded the file as mentiond in the answer attached so it's the in the path /Applications/Xampp/xamppfiles

Comment: you need to put an absolute path not a relative path

Comment: Careful if `open_basedir` is set, that it includes the directory where cacert.pem is located.

Comment: Are you sure the name of the file is cacert.pem or cacert.perm? Check the extensions correctly and make sure that's what you have in your environment's certificate path, usually locatedin the php.ini file at curl.cainfo ="C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.10/extras/ssl/cacert.pem"

Answer (score 39):

I got stuck on this problem as well. It turned out that I had the path to my certificate set incorrectly in my php.ini file. Forgot the .txt extension.

What I had:

```
curl.cainfo = "C:\xampp\php\cacert.pem"
```

What I changed it to:

```
curl.cainfo = "C:\xampp\php\cacert.pem.txt"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not working still. My file is called just "cacert.pem" no ".txt" extension.

Comment: @omarsafwany, perhaps your file extension may have been set to hidden. The certificate is basically a text file so the .txt extension should be added along with its absolute path. Restart your apache server too for these changes to take effect.

Comment: + may be try moving .pem file in 'bin/php/version-X.X/ext' folder.

Comment: For me it was a typical PEBKAC - while I configured (read: copy&pasted) "C:\xampp\...", the actual Xampp installation was in "C:\Program Files\xampp\...".

Comment: I must agree that the downloaded pem file was converted to a file with a .txt extension. Mine surprisingly worked when I changed it to cacert.pem.txt. I noticed this already that the file type is saved in text format but I was hesitant to use the .txt extension but eventually gave it a try and it worked.

Comment: In my case it's the relative path. You must specify the full path. In case you need it relative from the coding, you can determine the path dynamically using ``dirname(__FILE__).'/../cacert.pem'`` for example.

Answer (score 31):

> Add cacert.pem file from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem in
>   c:\xampp\php\cacert.pem
>
> Change setting in php.ini file:
>
> curl.cainfo = "C:\xampp\php\cacert.pem

Comment: Helped me to make GuzzleHttp php package work. Thanks mate.

Comment: Had to set `openssl.cafile` in `php.ini` to the same thing as well, but this worked for me.

Comment: Not working, I have litteral than you write here.

Answer (score 25):

My error is:

> cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: 
>   C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt CApath: none (see 
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

This works well for me:

1. Download the certificate from: https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
2. Rename the **cacert.pem** file into **curl-ca-bundle.crt**
3. Copy the file into **path/to/xampp/apache/bin**
4. Restart apache

Comment: Thank you. The "rename" saved my day. God Bless You

Answer (score 10):

I experienced some issues following instructions in regards to error 77.

On Windows 7, depending on your security settings - the file downloaded may be blocked. See screenshot:

[image: Windows 7 File Properties]

Once I unblocked the file and ensured proper user access rights, I also had to put the file in the following location:

> C:\xampp\apache\bin\cacert.pem.txt

In addition to changing php.ini per the other posts on this issue.

> curl.cainfo="C:\xampp\php\cacert.pem.txt"

After completing the above steps, restarting Apache via the XAMPP Control Panel, the error was resolved.

Answer (score 8):

1. Save this certificate (https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) as `cacert.pem.txt` in `C:\xampp\php`
2. Add to `php.ini`:

   ```
   curl.cainfo = "C:\xampp\php\cacert.pem.txt"
   ```
3. Don't forget to restart XAMPP (it won't work until it restarts)

Then it works fine!

Comment: Worked for me although I had to set my path accurately like ```"C:\wamp64\bin\php\extras\cacert.perm" or "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.1\extras\cacert.perm"``` . Also be sure to restart your web server after making changes to your php ini file.

Answer (score 8):

1. Download from (https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem)
2. Change the name '**cacert.pem**' to '**curl-ca-bundle.crt**' 
   (after that, move it to the path **'C:\xampp\apache\bin'**)
3. In '**php.ini**', **remove** '**;**' in the following line:
   **`curl.cainfo="C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt"`**

That works for me.

Comment: you should need to mention that the file shall be placed in " C:\xampp\apache\bin " path

Answer (score 6):

Checkout double quote on php.ini file:
if you copied and past from the Web maybe you got wrong double quote:

> ”C:\xampp\php\cacert.pem.txt”

instead of

> "C:\xampp\php\cacert.pem.txt"

Comment: Thank you, if you don't mention this I'd probably spend hours trying to figured out.

Comment: Oh man, this worked for me too - my last quote appears was incorrect. I don't believe I would have figured this out. You are a life saver - THANKS!

Comment: YES!!!! This one! Damn :)

Answer (score 4):

In your php.ini file, you should also update your

```
;openssl.cafile
```

with the same cacert.pem link you used in updating your

```
;curl.cainfo
```

Have a look at mine before and after

```
;curl.cainfo =

;openssl.cafile=
```

to

```
curl.cainfo ="C:\php-7.4.11\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"

openssl.cafile="C:\php-7.4.11\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
```

this fixes the cURL 60 error

```
curl.cainfo ="C:\php-7.4.11\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
```

while

```
openssl.cafile="C:\php-7.4.11\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
```

fixes the cURL 77 error.

Have fun!

NB: Do not forget to restart your server before trying it out.

For those who wish to find their php.ini file, use this command after you cd into your application

```
php -i | grep 'Configuration File'
```

Answer (score 3):

**For windows**

I had same problem after i updated **php** on window 2008. Suddenly all my **php** codes stopped working. What i did, i opned php.ini then i found a line

`;curl.cainfo =`

and i changed to

`curl.cainfo = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.0\cacert.pem"` **(remember to remove ; before curl.cainfo)**

and everything went to normal. What you need is to download a cert file [cert.pem](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) and place it anywhere on your server and change the line as i did in php.ini

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the existing certificate with the other one [here](https://gist.github.com/VersatilityWerks/5719158/download). After that:

- Extract and add it to `xampp\php\ext`
- Open `xampp\php\php.ini`
- Add this line `curl.cainfo='location from the first step'` to the end of the file.
- Restart and it should be working now.

This is the [source](http://codeontrack.com/solve-laravelxamppguzzlehttp-curl-error-60-no-sll-certificate/) link.

Answer (score 2):

This same problem with me in php version 8.0.3 on windows :
Solution was I had to uncomment and  set openssl.capath=path of certs in php.ini file.

I already set openssl.cafile so it was not throwing error for that but oepnssl.capath was not set sot error was there.

openssl.cafile="C:\Users\Akta\Softwares\php-8.0.3-nts-Win32-vs16-x64\extras\ssl\demoCA\cacert.pem"

openssl.capath="C:\Users\Akta\Softwares\php-8.0.3-nts-Win32-vs16-x64\extras\ssl\demoCA\certs"

Answer (score 1):

I read every thread I could find and this one provided the missing piece.

**Background:** I encountered this issue will trying to get Drupal 8 to check for available updates on a fresh development environment (wamp based).

1. **Get a copy of the Certificate data from Mozilla**, it can be found here:
   https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem 
   If you want to know more about what this is read this: https://serverfault.com/questions/241046/what-is-the-cacert-pem-and-for-what-to-use-that
2. **Save the file as "cacert.pem.txt" not as "cacert.pem"** This was the missing piece, thanks LyleK!. I have no clue why but you must have the .txt extension on the end or it does not work.
3. **Explicitly add the path to the location of the "cacert.pem.txt" file to your php.ini**

Example:

```
[curl]
; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an
; absolute path.
curl.cainfo = "C:\wamp\custom\cacert.pem.txt"
```

**If you are using a wamp stack restart it.** You should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to download your "curl.cainfo" file then you need to locate it to **C:\xampp\php\cacert.pem.txt**.

Second, you need to open your php.ini file in Xampp and copy this 
**=>**

**curl.cainfo = C:\xampp\php\cacert.pem.txt** anywhere you want.

Third please restart your **Apache Server** refresh your localhost page and that should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is running Windows with Plesk and they get this error.

You must ensure that the curl.cainfo path is inside the Plesk PHP directory otherwise you will get the error above even with the fix.

```
curl.cainfo = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP55\extras\ssl\cacert.pem.txt"
```

Fixed for me. Hope this helps someone, someday, somewhere.

Comment: And if you use Plesk in a shared host without access to the PHP directory, you can only set the curl option CURLOPT_CAINFO directly before each use.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried @mahesh-singh-chouhan, @omarsafwany, @LyleK solutions. but get same error repeatedly.

After that, I update php.ini file without double quotes & with **.pem** extension & I'm succeed to get desired result with below code.

```
curl.cainfo=E:\Xampp-5.6.3\php\ext\cacert.pem
```

I've also attached Screenshot.

Please first try above users suggestions, If failed also use this.

Thanks for solutions It creates way for me
@mahesh-singh-chouhan, @omarsafwany, @LyleK

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you did not read the error carefully, now read it carefully

cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: D:\XAMPP\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt CApath: none (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

it means you are missing a file called curl-ca-bundle.crt to verify certificate locations,
so you just need to put this(curl-ca-bundle.crt) file into your  XAMPP\apache\bin\ folder
and everything is fine error 77 has gone.

curl-ca-bundle.crt, to download the file you can use this link https://github.com/nirmalkumar98/nk

Comment: Man, you're awesome! I had dive many many resolutions and hadn't noticed: the location is.. Thank you, anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i tried every solution mentioned here and on other posts but none of them worked. I tried 
1) Setting proper file rights **( didn't work )** 
2) Changing file extension **( didn't work)**

then i moved the cacert.pem file inside php/ directory in xampp and restarted it, **it worked**. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
curl.cainfo = "C:\xampp\php\cacert.pem.txt"
```

hope it helps some one :)

Comment: If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to add quote for the file path. I was got the same error (77), that was because i forgot to add quotes. I solved the problem by adding that. ex: `"C:\AppServ\php\cacert.pem"`

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem in windows 2012

i had a virtual dedicated server that host for laravel

then i had this error and

- download that file from [here](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem)
- put in my extras folder in php 7.2
- in my php.ini file find this line

  [curl]

  ; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an

  ; absolute path.
     curl.cainfo = extras/ssl/cacert.pem
- i paste my download file into php file sth like this:

curl.cainfo = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.2\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
[image: cacert error rest api call curl php]

- then save php.ini
- then restart my iis or just website

[image: restart your iis windows 2012 cacert 77 error laravel php]

in my case i just restart my website

Answer (score 0):

For solve this error use this code :

```
 $client = new Client(['verify' => false ]);
```

And use this $client like this in your code:

```
   $headers = [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            RequestOptions::BODY => ' any code for your body ',
        ];

        $response = $client->request('POST', 'bar', [
            'headers' => $headers
        ]);

        $response = $response->getBody()->getContents();

        return $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

ULTIMATE SOLUTION THAT WORKS 2022, 2023, 2024

1. Download from [(https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem)][1]
2. Download the '`cacert.pem`' twice
3. Change the name of the second downloaded '`cacert.pem`' to '`cacert.crt`'
4. Place both files in `C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.4.26/extras/ssl/`
5. In your php.ini file from the wamp sever,
6. Uncomment `;curl.cainfo` & `;openssl.cafile`, be removing the semicolon before it.
7. Make changes as shown below:
   curl.cainfo ="C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.4.26/extras/ssl/cacert.perm"

   openssl.cafile="C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.4.26/extras/ssl/cacert.crt"
8. Restart wamp
9. It works like `merlin magic` (-_-)

Answer (score -1):

i had the same problem. you have to open the file .pem or pem.txt with a simple editor (bloc-note) and past the (https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) in your file. you have to reload apache.

Answer (score -5):

If it is related to git:

```
git config --global http.sslverify "false"
```

will solve the problem.

Comment: Down voted this response, disabling SSL is never a good solution.

Comment: It is not disabling SSL, only certificate validation. Still not a good solution though!