# Laravel 5.3 Socialite cacert.pem error in cpanel

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, laravel-socialite

I create a social login such as facebook, google & twitter. I did configure in local server `cacert.pem` and that's working. But my hosting cpanel is still throwing an exception:

> RequestException in CurlFactory.php line 187: cURL error 77: error
>   setting certificate verify locations: CAfile:
>   /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem CApath: none (see
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30240840/laravel-5-socialite-curl-error-77-error-setting-certificate-verify-locations

Comment: Yeah i solved it but i can't solve my c-panel.

Comment: Have you reached out to your hosting provider?

Comment: My hosting is share. Can i solve it?

Comment: Yeah i mail to him but his work so Delay.

Comment: @Serg Chernata Have any idea can i solve my share hosting?

Comment: My only guess is for you to look in cpanel for any certificate settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please no need to change in your share hosting you can go laravel-5.3 folder location 
foldername\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php

Open CurlFactory.php file go to applyHandlerOptions() then change

```
$conf[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = true;
```

to

```
 $conf[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = False;
```

I also fetch problem please try it may it's working.