# Trouble POSTing using cURL, PHP, and Basic Authentication

Tags: php, json, post, curl, postman

I made a similar post last week, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080854/i-need-help-converting-a-successful-request-from-postman-into-curl-commands-usin?noredirect=1#comment50182053_31080854). I was having problems with authentication, which I believe I've solved. The error message is different, at least.

I'm trying to recreate a successful POST I made to our vendor via POSTman by executing cURL commands in PHP.

Here is the example cURL command from their documentation:

```
curl -i -k -u '<api_key>': -XPOST --data-urlencode assessment_data@/path/to/test/file.json "https://<your_subdomain>.vendor.org/api/v1/import"; echo ""
```

This is my PHP code, which does not work:

```js
<?php session_start();
include('../connect.php');
include('../functions.php');

function curlPost($url, $headers, $username, $password, $post) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'certificate.pem');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    echo '<pre>';
    echo curl_exec($ch) . '<br><br>';
    echo print_r(curl_getinfo($ch)) . '<br><br>';
    echo curl_error($ch) . '<br><br>';
    echo '</pre>';
    curl_close($ch);
}

$data = 'JSON_object={"JSON_key":"JSON_value"}';

curlPost('https://company.vendor.org/api/v1/import',
    ['Content-Type: multipart/form-data'],
    'api-key',
    '',
    $data
);
```

and instead produces this output:

```js
{"success":false,"errors":["500 Internal Server Error"],"warnings":[],"info":[],"meta":[],"results":[]}

Array
(
    [url] => https://company.vendor.org/api/v1/import
    [content_type] => application/json; charset=utf-8
    [http_code] => 500
    [header_size] => 547
    [request_size] => 248
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 1.586493
    [namelookup_time] => 0.135777
    [connect_time] => 0.177182
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.286958
    [size_upload] => 1999
    [size_download] => 103
    [speed_download] => 64
    [speed_upload] => 1260
    [download_content_length] => 103
    [upload_content_length] => 1999
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.345878
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => xx.xxx.xx.xxx
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
         'This array is actually empty, I didn't delete anything.'
        )

    [primary_port] => 443
    [local_ip] => xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
    [local_port] => 60532
    [request_header] => POST /api/v1/import HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Host: company.vendor.org
Accept: */*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Content-Length: 1999
Expect: 100-continue


)
1
```

For good measure, here is a screenshot of a successful POST using POSTman (It's censored a little differently, but I'm passing in the exact same information):

[image]

Their documentation contains an example JSON object, which they save as a file and send as form-data. I've managed to recreate the object with live data, output it to a properly formatted string, and send that as the value instead. This works in POSTman, but not in my PHP, so I suspect the problem lies there somehow. CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS requires a string (tried an array - it got mad), and I've tried formatting it every way I can think of. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Turn on FireBug in Firefox or hit ctrl-shift-i in Chrome and actually look at the exact headers/data being sent in the request from POSTMan. You can even copy out the cURL request and convert it from the CLI version to what PHP uses (right click the URL in the Net panel). Try posting those headers here if you're not seeing the issue.

Comment: @BA_Webimax These are the headers directly from POSTman:

Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1786
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryBh3OUKXCFL7H96DQ
Cookie:BackendSessionID=814ce539e86dad2349de57316459df62; __uvt=; spinnerLeft=826px; spinnerTop=-4px
CSP:active
DNT:1

Comment: Host:company.vendor.org
Origin:chrome-extension://fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36

Comment: -------------- and these are the headers i'm sending w/ PHP: Host: company.vendor.org
Accept: */*
Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1495
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------2322a885f91a

Comment: I'm back to getting authentication issues