# getstream.io SSL certificate unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, laravel-5.1, getstream-io

I need some help. I'm integrating getstream.io into my laravel application (v5.1), I'm stuck with this error:

> cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
>   certificate

This is my code:

```
use GetStream\Stream\Client;

public function index()
{

 $client = new Client('rrzp7mz8htgn', '8cgs94jg2z5da2h4q2an8q6q5vktrp8y8w7rsft3zndf63c8y9n59g2h2qvtdhqq');

 $ericFeed = $client->feed('user', 'eric');

  $data = [
    "actor"=>"eric",
    "verb"=>"like",
    "object"=>"3",
    "tweet"=>"Hello world"
  ];
  $ericFeed->addActivity($data);

}
```

I followed the instructions below from packalyst

1. Add the get-stream into your composer:

   "require": {
       "get-stream/stream-laravel": "~2.1"
   },
2. then run composer update
3. I also added the provider and the aliases

   'providers' => array(
           'GetStream\StreamLaravel\StreamLaravelServiceProvider',
           ...
       ),

   'aliases' => array(
           'FeedManager'       => 'GetStream\StreamLaravel\Facades\FeedManager',
           ...
       ),
4. I run:

   php artisan vendor:publish --provider="GetStream\StreamLaravel\StreamLaravelServiceProvider"
5. I emailed already getstream.io, but no response yet. I'll be updated this post when I received some answers from them.

I also checked this post from laracast, but there's no answer.
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/activity-feeds-with-getstreamio?page=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getstream.io replied to my email and helped me, Here's the solution,

> the SSL error message it’s usually related to using old certificate
>   key chains with CURL. This is unfortunately quite of a common issue
>   with CURL and SSL, I suggest you to try the solution suggested in this
>   thread:
>   [Paypal Access - SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478283/paypal-access-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

and this is what i did:

1. Downloaded cacert.pem from the above link at curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and save it to c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/cert/
2. Click my wamp icon, navigate to PHP > php.ini
3. Added the following line and click save.

   curl.cainfo=c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/cert/cacert.pem
4. Restart wamp and that's it. it worked

Hope this helps other developers using getstream.io. Credits to Tommaso of getstream.io.