# Curl failed with response: 'unable to get local issuer certificate' on mailwizz

Tags: php, curl

Ive been trying to develop a payment gateway on mailwizz for a payment platform for my country and all was working....it all worked until i was trying to verify transaction using the payment gateway's class then i got that error...heres where i think the problem comes from in the payment gateway's class

```
private function callViaCurl($interface, $payload = [ ], $sentargs = [ ])
{


    $endpoint = PaystackHelpersRouter::PAYSTACK_API_ROOT . $interface[PaystackContractsRouteInterface::ENDPOINT_KEY];
    $method = $interface[PaystackContractsRouteInterface::METHOD_KEY];

    $this->moveArgsToSentargs($interface, $payload, $sentargs);
    $this->putArgsIntoEndpoint($endpoint, $sentargs);

    $headers = ["Authorization"=>"Bearer " . $this->secret_key ];
    $body = '';
    if (($method === PaystackContractsRouteInterface::POST_METHOD)
        || ($method === PaystackContractsRouteInterface::PUT_METHOD)
    ) {
        $headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
        $body = json_encode($payload);
    } elseif ($method === PaystackContractsRouteInterface::GET_METHOD) {
        $endpoint = $endpoint . '?' . http_build_query($payload);
    }

    //open connection

    $ch = curl_init();
    // set url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);

    if ($method === PaystackContractsRouteInterface::POST_METHOD || $method === PaystackContractsRouteInterface::PUT_METHOD) {
        ($method === PaystackContractsRouteInterface:: POST_METHOD) && curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        ($method === PaystackContractsRouteInterface ::PUT_METHOD) && curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
    }
    //flatten the headers
    $flattened_headers = [];
    while (list($key, $value) = each($headers)) {
        $flattened_headers[] = $key . ": " . $value;
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $flattened_headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // Make sure CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2 is defined as 6
    // Curl must be able to use TLSv1.2 to connect
    // to Paystack servers

    if (!defined('CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSV1_2')) {
        define('CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSV1_2', 6);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSV1_2);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch)) {   // should be 0
        // curl ended with an error
        $cerr = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        throw new Exception("Curl failed with response: '" . $cerr . "'.");
    }

    // Then, after your curl_exec call:
    $resp = json_decode($response);
    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);

    if (!$resp->status) {
        throw new Exception("Paystack Request failed with response: '" . $resp->message . "'.");
    }

    return $resp;


}
```

Comment: Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [curl: (60) SSL certificate : unable to get local issuer certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs when cURL tries to establish an encrypted connection but doesn't have a local certificate store necessary to determine which certs can be trusted.

There are two options:

**1** Add a setting to let cURL know where to find the local certificate store:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/path/to/cacert.pem');
```

**2** Or set the `CAINFO` within `php.ini` so that all cURL operations will use the same certificate file, without the need to set that option every time:

**php.ini**

```
[curl]
; A default value for CURLOPT_CAINFO option. Must be an absolute path.
curl.cainfo = "/path/to/cacert.pem"
```

I used [this pem file](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem), which I believe is a mirror of Firefox's internal certificate store.  Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175600/same-curl-script-works-in-dev-cant-figure-out-why-not-in-production)

Comment: thanks a lot for reply ill try and let you know if it works

Comment: i tried this one one of my domains with a cert it worked....but is there a way i can get it to work without ssl checking for test

Comment: @carrion to disable SSL checking, do `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`